# Negative Binomial Regression Questions

Tags: regression, cross-validation

First post!

I'm a biologist with limited background in applied statistics and R. Basically know enough to be dangerous, so I'd appreciate it someone could confirm/deny that I'm on the right path.

My datasets consists of count data (wildlife visits to water wells) as a response variable and multiple continuous predictor variables (environmental measurements).

First, I eliminated multicolinearity by dropping a few predictor variables. Second, I investigated the distribution of the response variable. Initially, it looked Poisson. However, a Poisson exact test came back as significant, and the variance of the response variable was around 200 with a mean around 9, i.e. overdispersed. Due to this, I decided to move forward with Negative Binomial and Quasipoisson regressions. Both selected the same model, the residuals of which are in a normal distribution. Further, a plot of residuals over predicted values is unbiased and homoscedastic.

Questions: 
1. Have I selected the correct regressions to model this data?
 2. Are there additional assumptions of the NBR and QpR that I need to test? How should I/Where can I learn about how to do these? 
3. Did I check for overdispersion correctly? Is there a difference in comparing the mean and variance vs comparing the conditional mean and variance of the response variable? 
4. While the NBR and QpR called the same model, is there a way to select which is the "better" approach? 
5. I know that NBR and QpR do not have homoscedastic assumptions. Is it meaningful that the model's plot of residual over predicted values is homoscedastic?
6. I would like to eventually publish. Are there more analyses I should perform on my selected model?

Comment: I would suggest using regularised negative binomial regression (as for example available in the packge [`mpath`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mpath/index.html) as to avoid explicit variable selections (unless of course you have expert knowledge that certain variables are redundant). (Welcome to the CV community!) Also, can you please comment on the source over-dispersion? Do you happen to have zero-inflation?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Each zero is a collected datum, i.e. no visits to water well on given day.

Comment: Let me be more specific... Overdispersion comes from many zero, one, and two counts with very few double digit visit counts (max of 65). Each count is a collected datum, i.e. no visits to water well on given day. No data were artificially generated.